# $f \in \mathcal{O}(\bar{\mathbb{D}})$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

ive got to solve this theorem,

If $f \in \mathcal{O}(\bar{\mathbb{D}})$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$, then $ B_r(0) \subset f(\mathbb{D})$ mit $r:=\dfrac{1}{6}|f|_\mathbb{D}$

while using this Lemma,

Let $G$ be a open bounded area, and f a static function $f: \bar{G} \to \mathbb{C}$ with $f|G : G \to \mathbb{C}$ open. And $a \in G$ a point, so that $s:= \min \limits_{z \in \partial{G}} |f(z)- f(a)|>0 $. This results in $ B_s(f(a)) \subset  f(G)$

How do I get $\min \limits_{z \in \partial{\mathbb{D}}} |f(z)|= 1/6 |f|_\mathbb{D}$ ?

Comment: Looks kind of like Bloch's Theorem.

Comment: @Sean This is an exercise in Remmert Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory at the start of the chapter 10 on Bloch Theorem

Comment: as noted below the problem is stated wrong as one needs $r:=\dfrac{1}{6|f|_\mathbb{D}}$ with easy counterexamples of $f_n(0)=0, f_n'(0)=1$ in which $r_n \to 0$ while $f_{n}|_\mathbb{D} \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f$ can have a zero on the boundary (eg $f(z)=z(1-z), f(0)=0, f'(0)=1, f(1)=0$) hence the minimum of $f$ on the unit circle can be zero, so the problem is slightly more subtle, but can be solved by brute force.

Also note that the actual problem is stated wrong as the disc we want has radius $\dfrac{1}{6|f|_\mathbb{D}}$ not $\dfrac{1}{6}|f|_\mathbb{D}$ as one can easily see by taking $f_n(z)=\frac{e^{nz}-1}{n}=z+...$ which obviously omits $-1/n$ so $r_n \to 0$ (where $r_n$ is the supremum of $r$ for which $D_{r}(0) \subset f_n(\mathbb D)$) while its maximum value on the circle is $\frac{e^n-1}{n} \to \infty$

Let $M= f|_\mathbb{D} \ge 1$ (by Schwarz lemma) and note that if $f(z)= z+\sum_{k \ge 2}a_kz^k$ one has by Parseval that $1+\sum_{k \ge 2}|a_k|^2 \le M^2$ so $|a_k| \le M$ (or of course one can use Cauchy to get same estimate)

But now if $|z|=\dfrac{1}{3M}$ the trivial majorization gives $|f(z)| \ge |z|-\sum_{k \ge 2}|a_k||z^k| \ge \dfrac{1}{3M} -\sum_{k \ge 2}\dfrac{M}{(3M)^k}=\dfrac{1}{3M} -\dfrac{1}{3M} \dfrac{1}{3M-1} $ and $1-\dfrac{1}{3M-1} \ge 1-\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$ since $M \ge 1$ so

$|f(z)| \ge \dfrac{1}{6M}$ for $|z|=\dfrac{1}{3M}$ and the lemma quoted in the OP applies and we are done!

Comment: Wow thank you very much that was incredible. I'm so sorry for misunderstanding the problem, that caused some problems in my version of the solution too. U did great :)